# Laravel 5.5 css path is not working under public directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used the following to generate the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

However, I see the css is not loading. From the view source, I see the below code which is not opening (404).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But, if I remove the "public keyword" from the above path, its working.

I'm using `php artisan serve` in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: you don't need to add `public`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

these two works. Because when `127.0.0.1:8000` load, it starts making the project from `public` path.

and `asset(/path)` is represent asset folder. You must change this with `public_path`

Comment: it shows now - <link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/html/stmd/public/global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> which is not working

Comment: try in terminal php artisan storage:link

Comment: The [public/storage] directory has been linked. but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asset()` helper,

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/global/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It should work, please verify you have files in public directory inside desired folder.

Comment: Yes, I have the said file(s) within the said path.